# How do I disable the message: "Android Studio is an application downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?" on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos

How do I disable the message: "Android Studio is an application downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?" on my MacBook Pro?

I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

[image]

Comment: Three should be a check where you can select **Never ask again for this app** or something like that. Or you may be trying to run Android Studio from an installer. Are you sure you are running it from Applications?

Comment: When does this happen, every time you login to your user account?

Comment: I'm definitely running it from applications and it happens every time I run the app (which is everyday).  There is no option to never ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable this kind of message. The reason is you have allowed to install apps from anywhere in the Security setting in System Preferences. If the app is from Mac App Store, you won't get any messages like this.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, the message should only ever appear once for an application and clicking Open should mean the message never appears again, as the app has been granted access through Gatekeeper. Otherwise everyone who uses apps outside the Mac App Store would be infuriated at constantly allowing apps — this doesn't happen!

Answer (score 1):

You can stop getting this message by removing the 'quarantine' flag from the app using this command:

`xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine “/Applications/Android Studio.app"`

if you get any errors, try it again with `sudo` like so:

`sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine “/Applications/Android Studio.app"`

Removing this flag stops macOS from checking the program for malware, and should only be done if you are absolutely certain that the program is safe. Use at your own risk, obviously.

Answer (score -2):

try `sudo spctl --master-disable` allow to instal from anywhere on mac

Comment: This answer needs a greater explanation of what that command does, and the consequences.